# Laravel "root" route variable

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following routes in Laravel. I wanna be able to call both countries as well as pages on the "root" of the domain, not with any directory prefix.

What I want to achieve is that when no page is found in the eloquent model, that it tries to go open the country and if that fails as well then show a 404.

Is that possible and what do I need to change?

```
Route::get('/{page}', 'PageController@view')->name('pages.view');
Route::get('/{country}', 'CountryController@view')->name('countries.view');
```

Edit: I think I was a bit unclear.
The issue is, that the `countries.view` route is never reached because it fails before with `pages.view`. Let's say I call `/germany` - it first matches the `pages.view` route but no page `germany` exists. It immediately throws a 404 but I want it to check the country after that and only fail if /germany doesn't exist as a country as well.

Comment: I think the routes as you've currently defined them are pretty ambiguous.  Laravel has no way to distinguish between a /{page} and a /{country} request.
I think what would work is a method in a controller where you parse the parameter passed, decide what to do with it and then redirect to the appropriate view

Answer (score 1):

How about being agnostic?
one route, you test the parameter, then returning the proper result.

```
Route::get('/{pageOrCountry}',function($pageOrCountry){
$page = App\Page::find($pageOrCountry);
if($page) return $page;
else $country = App\Country::find($pageOrCountry);
if($country) return $country;
else return redirect('404');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways I will mention two ways:

1- Route Model Binding :
    inside page controller create function

```
  public function view(Page $page){
   }
```

this function will return not found if page does not exists

2- Normal check :

```
   public function view($page){
    $check= Page::find($page);
     if(!$check) abort(404);
   }
```

Comment: I'm sorry I think I was a bit unclear in what I want. The issue is, that the "countries.view" route is never reached because it fails before with "pages.view". Let's say I call /germany - it first matches the "pages.view" route but no page "germany" exists. It immediately throws a 404 but I want it to check the country after that and only fail if /germany doesn't exist as a country as well.

Answer (score -1):

create resources/views/errors/404.blade.php folder and define 404 error message